# Nextjs suspense showing 'old UI' before updating

Tags: next.js, react-suspense, react-server-components

In my Nextjs application I am using suspense on a page route to display a loading skeleton until the content is ready.

The url is something like '/organization/:orgId/activity'.

I am using server components and fetching data from a planetscale database using Prisma in my ActivityList component.

If I go from one ..orgId/activity to another ..orgId/activity the following happens:

1. I see the skeleton loader that is the suspense fallback
2. I see the old activity list UI from the previous page
3. The old UI pops out and the new activity list is displayed.

And this keeps happening every time I navigate between the two routes (I also have the same issue with another component as well)

Here is the page component code:

```
const ActivityPage = async ({ params }: Props) => {
  const isSubscriped = await checkSubscription()
  

  return (
    <div className="w-full space-y-2">
      <Info isSubscriped={isSubscriped} />
      <Separator />
      <Suspense key={params.organizationId} fallback={<ActivityList.Skeleton />}>
        <ActivityList />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ActivityPage
```

And here is the ActivityList component with the skeleton loader code:

```
import { ActivityItem } from "@/components/activity-item"
import { Skeleton } from "@/components/ui/skeleton"
import { db } from "@/lib/db"
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs"
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"


export const ActivityList = async () => {
  const { orgId } = auth()
  
  if (!orgId) {
    redirect("select-org")
  }

  const logs = await db.auditLog.findMany({
    where: {
      orgId,
    },
    orderBy: {
      createdAt: "desc"
    }
  })

  return (
    <ol className="space-y-4 mt-4">
      {logs.length ? (
        logs.map((log) => <ActivityItem key={log.id} auditLog={log} />)
      ) : (
        <p className="block text-muted-foreground text-center text-sm">No activity found in this organization</p>
      )}
    </ol>
  )
}

ActivityList.Skeleton = function() {
  return (
    <ol className="space-y-4 mt-4">
      <div className="w-[75%] flex items-start gap-2">
        <Skeleton className="w-8 h-8 bg-neutral-200" />
        <Skeleton className="w-[75%] h-8 bg-neutral-200"/>
      </div>
      <div className="w-[75%] flex items-start gap-2">
        <Skeleton className="w-8 h-8 bg-neutral-200" />
        <Skeleton className="w-[60%] h-8 bg-neutral-200"/>
      </div>
      <div className="w-[75%] flex items-start gap-2">
        <Skeleton className="w-8 h-8 bg-neutral-200" />
        <Skeleton className="w-[75%] h-8 bg-neutral-200"/>
      </div>
      <div className="w-[75%] flex items-start gap-2">
        <Skeleton className="w-8 h-8 bg-neutral-200" />
        <Skeleton className="w-[55%] h-8 bg-neutral-200"/>
      </div>
      <div className="w-[75%] flex items-start gap-2">
        <Skeleton className="w-8 h-8 bg-neutral-200" />
        <Skeleton className="w-[80%] h-8 bg-neutral-200"/>
      </div>
    </ol>
  )
}
```

What I would expect to happen is that the skeleton loader keeps showing until the new activity list is ready to be displayed.

I have tried moving the fetching to the page component,
I have tried returning null if logs are not yet defined
I have tried looking for answers online without any luck
I have tried waiting for a new Promise that got resolved after 1 sec which does hide the ugly pop-in. But this caused Hydration errors and also was not really a solution.

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit:
Thanks to @Jung hyeonuk for helping me find the answer. Turns out that Clerk organization id was not updated yet, which caused the issue.

Added the setActive method on route change fixed the issue!

```
const onRouteChange = async (href: string) => {
await setActive?.({organization: organization.id})
router.push(href)
```

}

Comment: In my opinion, the old data is caused by default server side rendering of next.js. You're using router for rendering new data, so that each route move, there always are inital html with old data. Why don't you disable SSR by 'use client' or dynamic import and check if it works.

Comment: The reason I have not done it so far is because I wanted to fetch the data on the server. But maybe I can try to move the fetching to the page component and turn the ActivityList into CSR ? 
At least I will try to work with your suggestion, thanks

Comment: Making ActivityList CSR does prevent the pop in effect, but then also the loading state never happens and it looks very funcky (other stuff is not ready to be displayed yet, like Auth & organization info)

I cannot understand if there is no better way of doing this...

Comment: I think problem is related with orgId from 'auth'. Are you sure that it is 'new' when initial ssr? I mean if old data displayed in initial ssr, it means that orgId is not updated at that moment.
Also if you want to use both initial ssr(which I think valid solution), and csr afterwards, check this post. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77594572/react-suspense-works-but-only-partially/77595750#77595750

Comment: Thanks for all your help I will look into it as soon as I have time. I think you might be on to something about orgId not being updated

Comment: Thanks you Jung, you saved my sanity!

This totally worked, at least in dev env:

    

`
const onRouteChange = async (href: string) => {
    await setActive?.({organization: organization.id})
    router.push(href)
}
`

Sorry the codeblock wont seem to work for me..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a className: 'global' at the outermost div of your code and it will work.

```
    export default function Loading() {
  return <h2 className="global text-black dark:text-white">Loading...</h2>;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same tutorial and encountered the same problem.This is because pushing to the `/org/${orgId}` route doesn't update the current orgId, and when I reload the page it shows the old organization's data. Only after loading the new data does it return the correct information, thus creating a “bug”. The setActive function of the `useOrganizationList()` hook allows you to configure the correct organization before your `router.push()`